# Remove shortcuts from the side of the screen

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shortcut, settings

Have a nice day. Is there a hotkey to remove the region visible in the image?

[image]

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/gizmo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like, what you can do though is open the *Viewport Gizmos* panel, right click on *Navigate* and assign your own shortcut or assign it to your quick favorites:

[image]